# Check Files Existance from Shared Folder using Angular17 & ASP.NET Core v2.1

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, parameters, angular17

I used to have this AngularJS project where I used to call my API at this way:

```
$http.get(`${uriApi}api/PDS/CheckDirectoryExistance?path=` + encodeURIComponent(dirPath))
             .then(response => {
             if (response.data.ok) {
             docFound = true;
             LoadRootLevel(dirPath);
             Promise.resolve()
        }
         /*My Code Continues*/
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if (!alertShown) {
           docFolderFound = false;
           console.error("Error checking directory existence:", error);
           alert("There's no process documentation created for  '" + $scope.partNo + "'\nPlease verify that this is correct or ask your supervisor to provide the documentation." +
                 "Evaluating folders: \n" + dirs2 + "\n\nNo existe documentacion creada para el numero de parte '" + $scope.partNo + "'\nPor favor verifique que esto sea correcto o solucite a su supervisor la creacion de la documentacion"
            );
            alertShown = true;
        }
    });
```

But now I'm migrating my app to use Angular17 and ASP.NET Core.
The thing is that, my API didn't change basically.
As well here's my API Code:

```
[HttpGet("CheckDirectoryExistance/{path}")]
public ActionResult CheckDirectoryExistance(string path)
{
    try
    {
        bool directoryExists = Directory.Exists(path);
        return Ok(new { ok = directoryExists });
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return NotFound(ex);
    }
}
```

And here is my new TS code calling that API:

```
let dirs = [];
let dirPath = this.path + this.workSpaceInfo.userCell + "\\" + this.itemsInfo.partNo;
let alertShown = false;
console.log("DirPath? ", dirPath);
  try {
    let response = await this.http.get(`api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance/` + encodeURIComponent(dirPath)).toPromise();
    if (response == true) {
    docFound = true;
    this.LoadRootLevel(dirPath);
    console.log("directory found from response");
    }
    /* My code Continues*/
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error checking directory existence general catch:", error);
  }
```

The problem is:
I'm getting this error and I cannot find where's my error:

> GEThttps://localhost:44359/api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance/%5C%5CSharedFile01%5CPDS%5CX405%5CSt6%5C284A1733-170 404 (Not Found)
>
> Error checking directory existence general catch:
> message
> :
> "Http failure response for https://localhost:44359/api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance/%5C%5CSharedFile01%5CPDS%5CX405%5CSt6%5C284A1733-170: 404 OK"
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok: false
> status: 404
> statusText: "OK"
> url:"https://localhost:44359/api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance/%5C%5CSharedFile01%5CPDS%5CX405%5CSt6%5C284A1733-170"

I have already tried next:

1. I check the parameter passed in my API to be right and it is, it exist.
2. Added a breakpoint in my API to get in but never happend.
3. Changed API site (I changed from one controller to another).
4. I have another API's in my Controller that actually works, but this one does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I've noticed what my problem was:
My directory path has to be encoded being like this:

```
let dirPath = this.path + this.workSpaceInfo.userCell + "\\" + this.itemsInfo.partNo;
let encondedURL = encodeURIComponent(dirPath);
```

And I add that new variable to my API call:

```
let response = await this.http.get<any>(`api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance?path=` + encondedURL).toPromise();
```

But the change was in my API actually:

```
    [HttpGet("CheckDirectoryExistance")]
    public ActionResult CheckDirectoryExistance([FromQuery] string path)
    {
        try
        {
            bool directoryExists = Directory.Exists(path);
            return Ok(new { ok = directoryExists });
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error while Verifying the directory existance");
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }
    }
```

Notice that I removed the "{path}" from the route and I added "[FromQuery]". This because I was passing the string as a query parameter and I should use it as a route parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your api expects the raw format without encoding, so the simplest solution for you is replace

```
let response = await this.http.get(`api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance/` + encodeURIComponent(dirPath)).toPromise();
```

with

```
let response = await this.http.get(`api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance/${dirPath}`).toPromise();
```

Comment: also I'd recoment to use syntax with `Observable` instead if converting to `Promise` and `await`. But it is not related to the issue, just better practice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it doesn't worked as expected. Instead I got same error: 
url: `https://localhost:44359/PDS/api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance///SharedFile01/PDS/X405/St6/284A1733-170`

Comment: Could you show how does the request look like in a working version of the app. Inspect the network tab in chrome devtools and check the request itself and its headers. If you say backend hasn't changed, that means that request if different from the original one. Knowing the difference we will be able to identify the problem's reason.

Comment: In previous code the call used to be like this:
`var dirPath = path + userCell + "\\" + $scope.partNo;`
`$http.get(`${uriApi}api/PDS/CheckDirectoryExistance?path=` + `encodeURIComponent(dirPath))`
 `.then(response => { `

In my current one i tried to encode same as it was but seems like the call is taking the path as the API path and that's why I'm getting the error.
But in the headers tab this is what I see:
Request URL:`https://localhost:44359/api/PDSWorker/CheckDirectoryExistance/X405%5CSt6%5C284A1733-170`
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: yeah, this part `?path=` mean that the `path` must be taken from query params not wrom the URL itself. I'm glad that you finally solved it.